# Массив на javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, числа

Всем привет!
Необходимо создать массив такого вида [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]] ...
И так до 1000.
Напишите пожалуйста как, что-то не получается)

Comment: покажите, как именно не получается-то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вообще, нечто подобное по-моему уже было здесь.

вариант решения влоб:

```js
var n = 100, i= 1, k = 0, z = 0;
var data = [];

while( i <= n){
  if ( z == 0) {
    z = ++k;    
    data.push([]);
  }
  data[k-1].push(i++);
  z--;
}

console.log(data);
```

или пойти более понятным путем, сформировать исходный ряд и отрезать от него  увеличивающиеся кусочки

```js
//заполнить исходный
var data = [];
var n = 100;
while(n) data[--n] = n+1;


// порезать на части
var k = 0, result = [];
while(data.length){
   result[k] = data.splice(0, ++k);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)